# crud php fatal error Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo, crud

i have a little problem.

i have a contact-form and want to update my database with a crud.

My Contact-Form:

```
        <!-- UPDATE -->

        <div class="page-wrapper bg-gra-01 p-t-180 p-b-100 font-poppins">
        <div class="container">
        <?php
                if(isset($_GET['edit'])):
                    $result = $crud->getMember($_GET['edit']);
                ?>
                <hr />
                <div class="row mt-5">
                <h3> UPDATE </h3>
                <form method="post" action="formprocess.php" class="col-12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vorname" value="<?= $result['vorname']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Foto</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="Foto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="birthday" value="<?= $result['birthday']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5> Geschlecht </h5>
                        <select name="Geschlecht">
                            <option value=""> </option>
                            <option value=" Männlich" <?php if($result['Geschlecht'] == 'Männlich'){ ?> selected <?php } ?>> Männlich </option>
                            <option value=" Weiblich" <?php if($result['Geschlecht'] == 'Weiblich'){ ?> selected <?php } ?>> Weiblich </option>
                            <option value="Divers"      <?php if($result['Geschlecht'] == 'Divers'){ ?> selected <?php } ?>> Divers </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="input--style-3" type="email" placeholder="Max-Mustermann@gmail.com" name="email" value="<?= $result['email'];?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="input--style-3" type="text" placeholder="01575 2234455" name="phone"  value="<?= $result['phone'];?>">
                        </div>
                    <p> <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?= $result['ID']; ?>">
                    <p> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-Success" name="update" Value="Update"> </p>
                </form>
                </div>
                <?php
                 endif;
                ?>
```

My formprocess:

```
 if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['vorname']) && !empty($_POST['vorname']) &&
           isset($_FILES['Foto'])      && !empty($_FILES['Foto'])      &&
           isset($_POST['Geschlecht'])  && !empty($_POST['Geschlecht'])  &&
           isset($_POST['birthday'])    && !empty($_POST['birthday'])    &&
           isset($_POST['phone'])  && !empty($_POST['phone'])  &&
           isset($_POST['email'])  && !empty($_POST['email'])  &&
           isset ($_POST['ID'])  && !empty($_POST['ID'])
        ){
            $vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
            $pfad = "upload/";
            $filename = $_FILES['Foto'] ['tmp_name'];
            $name = $pfad . time() . "-" . $_FILES['Foto'] ['name'];
            $Geschlecht = $_POST['Geschlecht'];
            $birthday = $_POST ['birthday'];
            $phone = $_POST ['phone'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $ID = $_POST ['ID'];

            if(move_uploaded_file($filename,$name)){


           if($crud->updateMember($ID, $vorname, $name, $Geschlecht, $birthday, $phone, $email)) {
               $_SESSION['msg-class'] = "success";
               $_SESSION['msg'] = "Update war erfolgreich!";

               header('location: Admin.php');
           } else{
            $_SESSION['msg-class'] = "danger";
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!";

            header('location: Admin.php');
            }
            }
        }

    }
```

My crud.php:

```
        public function updateMember($ID, $vorname, $Foto, $Geschlecht, $birthday, $phone, $email) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE testing SET vorname = :vorname, Foto = :Foto, Geschlecht = :Geschlecht, birthday = :birthday, phone = :phone, email = :email WHERE ID=:ID");
            $erg = $stmt->execute(array(
                ':vorname' => $vorname,
                ':Foto' => $Foto,
                ':Geschlecht'  => $Geschlecht,
                ':birthday' => $birthday,
                ':phone' => $phone,
                ':email:' => $email,
                ':ID' => $ID
            ));

            return $erg;
```

If i press the Update button i get that error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\Xampp\htdocs\dashboard\pRAKTI\Testing 3\classes\crud.php:51 Stack trace: #0 C:\Xampp\htdocs\dashboard\pRAKTI\Testing 3\classes\crud.php(51): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\Xampp\htdocs\dashboard\pRAKTI\Testing 3\formprocess.php(66): Crud->updateMember('12', 'Boris', 'upload/16693640...', ' Weiblich', '0000-00-01', '666', 'b@web.de') #2 {main} thrown in C:\Xampp\htdocs\dashboard\pRAKTI\Testing 3\classes\crud.php on line 51

i don't know why, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution...
my code was apparently "unsorted". For example, I had the birthday in the 3rd place, but entered it as a 4th in the code

Comment: good job, good luck

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a PHP specialist, but I think your values and DB columns count mismatch. From the exception, I see that you have an invalid parameter number. You can post the whole file so we can debug it together.